# FetchAPI Response on DNS failure

Tags: javascript, browser, chromium

I am trying something like:

```
const resp = await fetch('http://bad-domain'); //bad-domain does not resolve
```

I am then catching an exception later in my code that reads:
`TypeError: failed to fetch`

Is this the expected result of a failed DNS lookup or is this due to `resp` coming out as different from the normal `Response` object that an error free `fetch` returns.

It is just that `TypeError` does not clearly indicate that the issue is a bad network request and not bad javascript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [expected behavior](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-method):

> 12.3. If response is a network error, then reject *p* with a `TypeError` and terminate these substeps.

...where *p* is the promise returned by `fetch`. The specification doesn't require any specific information be provided about *why* the request failed, just *that* it failed (at the network level; it doesn't reject on HTTP errors, as [I describe here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) on my old anemic blog, you have to check that on the fulfillment path).

Comment: *(FWIW, using `TypeError` for this seems odd to me, too, but then that's not my only issue with the `fetch` API [see link above].)*

Comment: Thanks for the canonical reference. I skimmed the spec but must have missed it. MDN is also a bit unclear

Comment: @doron - Oh wow, I just looked at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#exceptions and that's not just unclear, it's flat out wrong or at least fairly misleading, suggesting you only get a TypeError when there are credentials in the URL. I have three other MDN edits on my list for the next couple of weeks, I'll add this to it. :-)

Comment: @doron - [#9377](https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/9377).

Comment: Nice one. Thanks